# Функция, проверяющая делятся ли элементы списка на делитель

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно создать функцию, которая берет два аргумента: первый - это список чисел, а второй аргумент это делитель. Функция должна возвращать новый список с элементами исходного списка, которые не делятся нацело на второй аргумент

```
def list_filter(int_values, div):
   new_list=[]
   if div >= 1:
       return None
   if len(int_values) == 0:
       return None
   else:
       for x in range(int_values):
           if x % div != 0:
               new_list += str(x)
               if type(x) != int:
                   return None
       return new_list
a = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(list_filter(a,2))
```

Выше мой вариант решения возвращает просто `None`

Answer (score 2):

> мой вариан решения возвращает просто None

Немудрено, ведь

```
if div >= 1:
   return None
```

Comment: вот бы людей сразу учили пользоваться отладчиком и выводом промежуточных состояний!

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто. В if div >= 1 был неправильно поставлен знак,а ещё в else нужно было перебрать все значения списка и добавить в новый список с помощью .append вот так:

```
if div <= 1:
       return None
   if len(int_values) == 0:
       return None
   else:
       for x in int_values:
           if x % div != 0:
               new_list.append(x)
       return new_list
```

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо, что указали на ошибку. Ответ отредактирован.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
d = 3
res = list(filter(lambda x: x%d, a))
print(res)
```